# Kotlin: Best way to save account information

Tags: android, kotlin, settings

I am trying to develop an android app and I have the following issue:

I want to save the bank account information of a user which should look like this:

1. Name, Surname or Company
2. Adress (Street + Number, ZIP-Code, Country)
3. IBAN

is there a better way than to use EditText for 1 and 3 and EditTextPostalAdress?

Secondly, how do I save such a profile that it does not reset when closing the app?

Thank you in advance,
rot8

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCompanyName"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/AccountName"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPostalAddress"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextIBAN"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/iban"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It would be much better if you would post some code for us can analize it and better helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are actually using 3 `EditText` widgets, with one specifying `android:inputType="textPostalAddress"`. That is the correct way of doing that, there is no special view for that purpose.
2. What you're really asking is how to **persist data** in an Android app. Meaning, how to store information even if the app is killed. There are many ways to do so, the common ways being a local Database (check out [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)), [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) or a dedicated remote server (check out [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)). It usually depends on the type of data you need to store, and/or the purpose of your app.
   For more information, please refer to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage).